# getting an issue in sklearn.linear_model._logistic in ml

Tags: python, scikit-learn

can anyone tell me how to fix this?
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model._logistic'

File "c:\users\chintan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)
File "C:\Users\chintan\Desktop\streamlit\Final_year_project\App.py", line 329, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\chintan\Desktop\streamlit\Final_year_project\App.py", line 264, in main
loaded_model = load_model("logistic_regression_hepB_model.pkl")
File "C:\Users\chintan\Desktop\streamlit\Final_year_project\App.py", line 96, in load_model
loaded_model = joblib.load(open(os.path.join(model_file),"rb"))
File "c:\users\chintan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 588, in load
obj = _unpickle(fobj)
File "c:\users\chintan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 526, in _unpickle
obj = unpickler.load()
File "c:\users\chintan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\pickle.py", line 1088, in load
dispatchkey[0]
File "c:\users\chintan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\pickle.py", line 1376, in load_global
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "c:\users\chintan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\pickle.py", line 1426, in find_class
**import**(module, level=0)

Comment: Got same error with details below using scikit-learn==version 0.22.2.post1 and joblib version 1.0.1

Comment: obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1210, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1526, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1577, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model._logistic'

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a version like: `pip install scikit-learn==0.22`